# Как в CSS задать курсив для всех абзацев <p>, а для первого - не задавать

Tags: css

Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:

> Сделайте все абзацы `<p>` курсивом, а первый абзац - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте присвоить нужным абзацам классы, и установите в CSS им курсив.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```css
p~p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
```

Comment: Это работает только если все абзацы идут подряд.

Comment: Исправил. Теперь не обязательно подряд.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  font-style: italic;
}

p:first-child {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
```

```css
p:not(:first-child) {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
```

```css
* + p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
<p>Препод задал задание, которое звучит так:
```

Comment: Селектор `p+p`. Это же очевидно!

Comment: В условии не сказано, что все абзацы идут подряд ;)

Comment: Если не подряд, то `p~p`. В этом случае ограничение в том, что они селектор работает с параграфами на одном уровне.